# Is this a new strange attractor?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, chaos

I recently made some experiments in programming strange attractors, and I found this (very simple) equations, which create a nice strange attractor:

```
xn=x+dt*(z-y)
yn=y+dt*(x/2-1)
zn=z+dt*(-xy/2-z)
```

You can see it in action on my Youtube channel:
https://youtu.be/Bm_M6mUGjtg

My question: Is this a variation of the Lorenz- or Rössler attractor - or did I stumble upon something new?

---

**EDIT:**

Meanwhile I programmed a little 3D View for this attractor:

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can see/move the view on this applet (Java needed):
https://cerumen.de.cool/attractor/index.html
(Here you also find the source code for Processing)

And here the Javascript-Version: https://cerumen.de.cool/attractor/js/index.html (with processing.js... bit slow)

Perhaps my question was also asked too amateurishly.
I was simply surprised by the simplicity of the system of equations I have found.

Therefore I would like to know if this strange attractor is a descendant of one of the well known ones (Lorenz / Rössler).

---

**Edit 2:**

I have now brought the system of equations into a more general form:

```
xn=x+dt*(z-y)
yn=y+dt*(ax-b)
zn=z+dt*(-axy-z)
```

with a in range [0 to 1], b in range [0.5 to 1]

This makes it more interesting.
Here some sample images for different values for a and b:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

---

**Edit 3:**

Here a video with the generalized equations and constantly changing parameters a and b: https://youtu.be/gxusM8pmNwU

I think you can see here quite well how the system goes from order through bifurcation into chaos...

Comment: I believe it is not that difficult to cook up new fractals - there is plenty of software products out there that does this, Flamethyst for example (although the method is a bit different).

Comment: It's certainly _very_ close to the Rossler system: two coordinates with linear differential equations, one 'slightly' nonlinear one, with a quadratic perturbation term. While the specific form of the linear piece is slightly different, I wouldn't be surprised if the two are fundamentally equivalent in some fashion.

Comment: Thank you, Steven, I kind of suspected that too. But so far I have not found a way to transform the Rössler equations into my system of equations. I think this is the core of my question.

Comment: As Per Alexandersson suggests, strange attractors are actually very common for nonlinear systems in three variables.  You can literally make up new ones just by making up a system of nonlinear differential equations and then using some graphing software to check whether it has a strange attractor. There are certain "famous" strange attractors which are famous mostly for historical or scientific reasons, but there are lots of unnamed strange attractors associated with various systems.  This *is* a particularly nice one and you've made some great pictures of it, but it's not really very novel.

Comment: Thank you, @Jim, for your answer. It seems that the answer to my question is: This is just _another_ new strange attractor. But I still love the simplicity of the equation system, which really surprised me when I programmed this thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In another forum a user drew my attention to the publication of

- J. C. Sprott, *Some simple chaotic flows*, Phys. Rev. E **50**, R647-R650 (1994), doi:[10.1103/PhysRevE.50.R647](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevE.50.R647), [author pdf](http://sprott.physics.wisc.edu/pubs/paper212.pdf).

This shows that there are many very simple chaotic systems of equations.

I guess this answers my question...

You can see some of the equations [here](http://sprott.physics.wisc.edu/pubs/paper212.htm), and [here](http://sprott.physics.wisc.edu/simplest.htm) are the corresponding graphs.

But thank you all for your interest.

Answer (score 5):

I just figured I added some Mathematica code and a picture for the attractor in the question.

[image: Picture of x-y plane of attractor]

```
With[{dt = 0.001},
  iter[{x_, y_, z_}] := {x, y, z} + 
    dt {(z - y), x/2 - 1, -x y/2 - z} 
  ];
pts = NestList[iter, {0.1, 0.1, 1/2}, 500000];
ListPlot[{#1, #2} & @@@ pts[[1 ;; ;; 5]], PlotRange -> All, 
 Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.9], PointSize[Tiny], Orange}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, Background -> Gray, ImageSize -> {800, 600}]
```

I only plotted every fifth of the points, as it is a bit quicker, and the image is a bit more pleasant with this variant.

**EDIT:**

With some more creative edits,
$$
(x_{n+1}, y_{n+1}, z_{n+1}) =(x_n, y_n, z_n)+dt
(z - y, -1 + x + 6 \sin(\pi/4 + 10 x/ z), -x y/2 - z)
$$
one can produce the following picture.
Adding any non-linear disturbance, and making sure that it does not diverge, or converge to something boring, it is rather easy to cook up exotic variations that give rise to chaotic behavior.

[image: attractor 2]

Comment: Per, thank you for your detailed explanations. But my question is not how to create chaotic systems with increasing complexity.
What I want to know is whether my really simple system of equations is some sort of derivative of already known attractors.